# How to make a Django custom management command argument not required?

Tags: python, django, command

I am trying to write a custom management command in django like below-

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('delay', type=int)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        delay = options.get('delay', None)
        print delay
```

Now when I am running `python manage.py mycommand 12` it is printing 12 on console. Which is fine.

Now if I try to run `python manage.py mycommand` then I want that, the command prints 21 on console by default. But it is giving me something like this-

```
usage: manage.py mycommand [-h] [--version]
                           [-v {0,1,2,3}]
                           [--settings SETTINGS]
                           [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH]
                           [--traceback]
                           [--no-color]
                           delay
```

So now, how should I make the command argument "not required" and take a default value if value is not given?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to change this `delay = options.get('delay', None)` to this `delay = options.get('delay', 21)` to handle defaults? Just a guess.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

One of the recipes from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#default) suggests:

> For positional arguments with nargs equal to `?` or `*`, the `default` value is used when no command-line argument was present.

So following should do the trick (it will return value if provided or default value otherwise):

```
parser.add_argument('delay', type=int, nargs='?', default=21)
```

Usage:

```
$ ./manage.py mycommand
21
$ ./manage.py mycommand 4
4
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use the dash syntax for optional keyword arguments:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument("-d", "--delay", type=int)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        delay = options["delay"] if options["delay"] else 21
        print(delay)
```

Use:

```
$ python manage.py mycommand -d 4
4
$ python manage.py mycommand --delay 4
4
$ python manage.py mycommand
21
```

Docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/#s-accepting-optional-arguments

Simple explanation:

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/08/27/how-to-create-custom-django-management-commands.html#handling-arguments

Comment: That doesn't work because you don't know if the user put in 21 or it defaulted to 21.

Comment: @noone392 Thats not true, you can easily check if it defaulted by checking `if options["delay"]`. My example was specific simply setting a value to 21 when `options["delay"]` is falsey, which corresponds to the parameter not being passed and thus is the case where we should use the default value.