# What is the purpose of default=False in django management command

Tags: python, django, django-management-command

I'm trying to write a management command in django. According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/) default is set to False. I would assume that the default is the default value of the argument that is being passed.
[Make django custom management command argument "Not Required"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35635128/make-django-custom-management-command-argument-not-required)

What's the benefit of stating that `deafult=False`

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "helps in doing stuff"

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument(
            'name', type=str, default=False,
            help="The name of the folder to be created")

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        pass
```

Comment: what do you mean by "according to the documentation default is set to false"? You can set default to whatever you want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [first example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/) in the docs you link to is for an optional named argument `--delete`. Setting `action='store_true'` means that if you include `--delete` in the command, then `args.delete` will be set to `True`, and if `--delete` is not included in the command then it will `default=False`.

In this case, setting `default=False` isn't actually required, because that's the behaviour of `action='store_true'`. The advantage of explicitly setting `default=False` is that the behaviour is clear without needing to look up the `argparse` docs.

```
    parser.add_argument(
        '--delete',
        action='store_true',
        dest='delete',
        default=False,
        help='Delete poll instead of closing it',
    )
```

Your example does not make sense, because `name` is not an optional argument.

```
parser.add_argument(
    'name', type=str, default=False,
    help="The name of the folder to be created")
```

If you try this example then you will get an error like `too few arguments`.

```
parser.add_argument(
    'name', type=str, default=False
    help="The name of the folder to be created")
```

You need to set `nargs='?'` if you want he `name` argument to be optional. In this case, your default will be used. If you didn't set it, then it will default to `None`

```
parser.add_argument(
    'name', type=str, nargs='?', default=False,
    help="The name of the folder to be created")
```

Note that if your argument is the 'name of the folder to be created', it might not make sense to set the default to `False`. It seems like either the argument should be required (in which case no default is needed) or the default should be a string e.g. `/path/to/folder/`.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `default` is what the argument will be set to if it's not passed in to the command.

In your case, if you call your command and don't provide a `name` through the CLI, `options['name']` will be set to `False` (your `default` value).

Comment: For the example above, `name` is a required argument, so the default won't be used. Instead, you'll get `error: too few arguments`.